# What is the name of cell structures that have an adaptation to increase their surface area?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, cell-membrane

Epithelial cells that line the small intestine have an adaptation to increase their surface area - what is the name of these structures? And why would the small intestine require a large surface area?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I already found microvillus before coming on here, just to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called [microvilli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microvillus), that forms the [brush-border](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brush_border) of [villi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intestinal_villus)

Answer (score 1):

The small intestine requires a high surface area in order to increase the rate of absorption of digested food.

Comment: The greater surface area also provides for more secretion of the "brush border" enzymes responsible for the finishing touches of digestion.